# Multiline Tabbar Text Editor on Linux

Tags: linux, text-editor, tabbar, multiline

I'm looking for text editor that run natively on linux which support multi-line tabbar and don't truncate long file names. I'm usually using Notepad++ in Windows.

Here is a screenshot of what I would like (using notepad++):
[image: multi-line tabbar]

Please give me recommendation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The top 3 seem to be the following:

[sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/), I guy I work with loves this one and it is cross os compatible.

[geany](http://www.geany.org/), great for if you do programming and are a GTK2 fan.

[kate](http://kate-editor.org/), KDE editor with LOTS of options
[vim](http://www.vim.org/), what most will tell you to use....

Additionally you can install Notepad++ through Wine, if you just cant live without it. :)

Comment: I've tried sublime and geany, both doesn't support multiline tabbar. Kate said that it's support multiline tabbar (http://kate-editor.org/2011/04/25/kates-tab-bar-plugins/) but I failed to configure it in Ubuntu 12.04. Ubuntu 12.04 uses KDE 4.8

I'm big fans of native apps, so maybe Wine will be the last choice. :)

Thanks for suggestion, Matt.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [atom](https://atom.io/packages/multirow-tabs). It's highly configurable through CSS and even is cross-platform.

[image]